# Is there an organized list of the published D&D Dungeon and Dragon magazine adventures?

Tags: dnd-4e, published-adventures

I have access to both Dungeon and Dragon Magazines through my D&D Insider subscription, but WOTC only lists their articles in the database by title. What would really help is if it a list exists categorizing the adventures by level, setting, and story path (if they have one). Does this exist?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[There is](https://spreadsheets.google.com/pub?key=0AgVSv2n9lvwndGEyOVhILURBLVBFWWMwNlJIcjdIZnc&hl=fr&output=html)!

This list is organized by setting, adventure path and level.

I do not know who maintains it (I found it in a deep dive through Wizards' forums a while ago and I have no idea who is responsible for it), but it is well maintained. And I have found at least one error (one of the adventures listed as a L4 in the Chaos Scar path is actually a 3). However, this file has been immensely useful to me in my preparations to GM a Chaos Scar game.

Comment: The link is dead.